# invalid conversion from int to int c++

Tags: c++, winapi, variables

I'm trying to make something in WinAPI but I get big loads of errors, corrected most of them but i cant find solution to that one:

```
for (LPINT i = 1; i <= ilosc; i++)
```

The compiler shows that error is is the "1".

I would post the entire code but its so unorganized that it would be hard to find this line in it the loop for declares its own variable so i think that I'm using the wrong type of variable (no clue what would be correct)

I changed the names of every variable I have to `LP*` and it solved almost all of my problems except this one.

Also if someone is well oriented in the topic of WinAPI could you teach me how to declare a variable in a textbox? I want to use textboxes as input sources for the variables so the program would count on numbers I type there? (the most of tutorials is written in very scientific language so I cant clarify myself good)

Also I know how bad at typing I am and that it lacks capitalization, punctuation, etc (I wasn't listening on language lessons in primary school and this mistake keeps showing off so don't rage at me cause I'm fixing it).

Comment: `LP` means pointer. You can't initialize a pointer with 1. In any sort of IDE, mousing over it would give you the type.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why did you choose `LPINT`?

Comment: I want to make a loop that actualy works in winapi (in school we arent so deep within c++ yet) so i can make more loops which i will adjust to my liking. This one has to serve as simple tryout so i will know how to make other loops. I chose lp int because when i wrote LP before int in other parts of the program (not loops) it stopped showing the errors

Comment: Loops have nothing to do with winapi, it's basic C/C++.

Comment: Well, if it worked in other parts of the program, it **must** work here! Change your compiler.

Comment: `I changed the names of every variable I have to LP*` You mean `types` instead of `name`s here?

Comment: It's also worth noting that array indices are zero-based in C/C++. Even if this isn't an array index it's good practice to write loops as `for ( int i = 0; i < count; ++i )`.

Comment: "when i wrote LP before int in other parts of the program (..) it stopped showing the errors" -- that is [Cargo Cult Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)

Comment: You should not try to learn the Windows API, event-driven GUI programming, and C++ all at the same time. Concentrate on the basics, get a solid understanding of C++ first. Console applications are boring, but it'll pay off to not try to get ahead of yourself.

Comment: I'm just staggered, quite unbelievable

Comment: Perhaps you should try `LPfor (LPINT LPi = 1; LPi <= LPilosc; LPi++)`

Answer (score 3):

`LPINT` is a long pointer on int. Thats why you cannot assign a `1` to that variable.

Comment: Actually, it's a long pointer to an `int`. Long pointers do not mean anything special anymore in a flat memory model. Long pointers were relevant in a segmented memory model, and are a leftover of 16-bit Windows.

Comment: Well thanks for correcting me, I've edited the answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

`LPINT` is a typedef for `typedef int *LPINT` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx)

It's a pointer, not an int.